# What does 'gatekeeper' mean in most cases?

Tags: word-usage

The sales in our company use gatekeeper to indicate the market leads dispatcher. But I am not sure why gatekeeper is not for those who sanitize the leads. I want to know the most common usage of this word.

Answer (score 2):

A *Gatekeeper* is a person who is employed to control who goes through the gate. The person is a *Watchman*.

This is the most common usage of the word [gatekeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatekeeper/). It has been extended to any person who performs a check before permitting an action to take place.

For example: An admissions officer who checks if the applicant's application is valid, before sending the application to the respective department.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Nagarajan, but I'd add that 'gatekeeper' has a connotation of strictness.

For example, a toll booth operator is a form of gatekeeper, but lets anyone through who pays.  A doorman is a bit more of a gatekeeper, since he will only open the door for 'desirables' - people he knows are allowed into the building, or appear to have legitimate business there.

A bouncer at a club is even more of a gatekeeper, in that his job is more to keep people out than let them in.

So, most people would describe a bouncer as a gatekeeper, but not so much a toll booth operator or a doorman.

There's also a metaphorical use, occasionally humorous: "You need a new stapler? Go see Shelley, she's the gatekeeper of the office supplies!"

In your particular example, your market leads dispatcher has a similarly valuable resource (the leads), who controls who gets access to which ones.  Hence, he's a gatekeeper.

Comment: The connotation of strictness in my answer is provided by the line *who performs a check before permitting an action to take place* in a generic way. You have provided few concrete examples to make it clear.

Comment: I tried to emphasize with my examples that "gatekeeper" is generally used to describe someone whose job is more to *deny* access than to permit it. That is, a gatekeeper is more like Cerberus guarding the gates to the underworld and less like the greeter at Walmart. ;-)